# Somar dados trimestrais em colunas

Tags: microsoft-excel

Estou com a seguinte duvida:

Tenho 5 colunas...cada uma com informações trimestrais;

```
Consolidado        31/12/2006   31/03/2007  30/06/2007  30/09/2007  31/12/2007 ....
Reserva de Lucros   12300         12300        646      646           33283  ...
Receita liquida     92479         61524        141850   255179        384120    ... 
Lucro antes jurEBIT 17403         7386          23136   -23           32695  ...
Resultado financeir -3072          829          5288    16615         36681  ...
Receitas Financ      1107          2735         7469    22613         43320  ...
LAIR                  14331        8215         28424   16592         69376 .....
```

Estou procurando uma função que me dê a soma dessas informações, e organize esse somatório na matriz abaixo, pois preciso da informação em periodo anual:

Ou seja, quero que a função alimente a matriz abaixo, ja com as somas feitas:

```
Consolidado        2006           2007         2008     2009          2010 ...
Reserva de Lucros   -               -          -        -             -     ...
Receita liquida     -               -          -        -             -  
Lucro antes jurEBIT -               -          -        -             -  
Resultado financeir -               -          -        -             -   
Receitas Financ     -               -          -        -             -      
LAIR                -               -          -        -             - ...
```

É possivel?

Comment: Removi as tags 'wordpress' e 'xml' porque elas não parecem fazer sentido na sua pergunta. E no futuro, procure fornecer uma planilha Excel com os dados de exemplo para evitar que alguém interessado em responder precise copiar os dados da pergunta. Não custa nada da sua parte, e evita que as pessoas deixem de te responder por falta de tempo ou preguiça.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a função [`SOMASE`](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-SOMASE-5fd078db-e5f8-4726-b08f-74fd0064e7fe?ui=pt-BR&rs=pt-BR&ad=BR) para fazer a soma condicional para cada ano.

Para facilitar, crie uma linha (no meu exemplo eu chamei de "Escondida") para conter apenas o ano de cada data, em cada coluna. Você pode usar a função [`ANO`](https://support.office.com/pt-BR/article/ANO-Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ANO-c64f017a-1354-490d-981f-578e8ec8d3b9?CorrelationId=3086f922-676e-4f6e-9094-7d57c01f06a7&ui=pt-BR&rs=pt-BR&ad=BR) para extrair somente o ano, mas lembre-se de formatar as células como número ao invés de data. Essa linha serve só pra facilitar o restante do cálculo e pode ser escondida do usuário selecionando a linha toda, clicando com o botão direito do mouse sobre a linha e escolhendo "Ocultar":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tendo-se essa linha com os anos, basta usar a função `SOMASE` para somar o valor de cada linha (Consolidado, Reserva, Receita, Lucro, etc) somente para o ano da coluna, em uma nova "tabela" (que no exemplo eu coloquei abaixo da original. A chamada da função tem a seguinte sintaxe:

```
=SOMASE(REGIÃO_DE_TESTE; CRITÉRIO_DE_TESTE; REGIÃO_DE_SOMA)
```

Assim, por exemplo, para calcular o lucro total de 2007, a fórmula fica assim:

```
=SOMASE($B$2:$F$2;C$11;$B5:$F5)
```

Conforme a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu usei o cifrão (`$`) para fixar as linhas/colunas que não mudam conforme a fórmula é copiada e colada.

O arquivo de exemplo [pode ser baixado do 4Shared aqui](http://www.4shared.com/file/xweD3Cp8ba/TesteSOPT__1_.html).